# Mongodb aggregation pipeline with $setIntersection

Tags: database, mongodb, go, aggregation-framework

I'm currently using golang to create an aggregation pipeline where I'm querying documents with an "$or" operator.

The result is a bunch of ungrouped documents that I need to group so that I can pass to the next stage that finds the intersection between the two datasets.
This is then used to make a lookup in a separate collection

```
{
                "$match": bson.M{
                    "userID": bson.M{"$lt": afterID},
                    "$or": []bson.M{
                        // "follower": myID,
                        {"follower": myID},
                        {"follower": personID},
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                "$group": bson.M{
                    "_id":       "$follower",
                    "followers": bson.M{"$push": "$userID"},
                },
            },
            {
                "$project": bson.M{
                    "common": bson.M{"$setIntersection": []interface{}{string("$" + myID.Hex() + ".followers"), string("$" + personID.Hex() + ".followers")}},
                },
            },
}
```

The problem is that in the "project" stage I need to somehow reference the IDs, which despite being known prior to making the query, cannot be substituted with their string representations.

I know this because the value is always resolving to null despite having common values.

How can I achieve this, or even model my query in a way that this becomes straightforward without chunking the queries and manually finding the intersection?

Comment: Cheki https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/

Comment: Nlikua nmepitia hio, but thanks. Good to know kuna msee ako similar industry from around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `$group` stage, there will be 2 documents in the pipeline, one with `_id:myId` and one with `_id:personID`.

The `$project` stage operates on a single document at a time, and cannot reference fields from other documents.

In order to see both at the same time, use a second group stage and push both followers arrays into an array of arrays, then you can have the project stage get the intersection of the first two elements of the combined array.

```
            {
                "$group": bson.M{
                    "_id":       "$follower",
                    "followers": bson.M{"$push": "$userID"},
                },
            },
            {
                "$group": bson.M{
                    "_id":       null,
                    "combined": bson.M{"$push": "$followers"},
                },
            },
            {
                "$project": bson.M{
                    "common": bson.M{"$setIntersection": []interface{}{
                       bson.M{"$arrayElemAt":[]interface{}{"$combined",0},
                       bson.M{"$arrayElemAt":[]interface{}{"$combined",1}
                    }},
                },
            },
```

Comment: Your code has a few syntax errors though, but nothing I couldnt figure out